# Create Range Column with duplicate values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column, call it `range_id`, that looks something like this:

```
range_id
1
1
2
2
5
5
5
8
8
10
10

...
```

I want to maintain the number buckets (each rows that share values still share values), but make the numbers ascend uniformly. So the new column would like this:

```
range_id
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
5
...
```

I could write a lambda function that maps these in such a way to achieve this desired output, but I was wondering if pandas has any sort of built-in functionality to achieve this, as it has always surprised me before in what it is capable of doing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is dup.......

Comment: `df['range_id'].rank(method='dense')` .

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the other questions as I didn't know the rank method, which makes it pretty difficult to search.

Comment: @ayhan should I delete this question? Sorry, not entirely sure how to handle the situation.

Comment: @the_deuce We generally keep the duplicate questions so that people searching with different keywords can find the questions more easily. It is completely up to you at this point though.

Comment: @ayhan ok, I will keep it if it serves a purpose, I just wanted to make sure I was following the forums guidelines. Thanks for the clarification, and for posting the method I was looking for!